# A simple C program to reverse every line of input. I have finished it. But I keep getting �$

Tags: c

Write a program that reverses every line of input. You may assume none of the input lines will be longer than 100 characters.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c[100];
    fgets(c,100,stdin);
    for(int i=sizeof(c); i>=0; i--) {
        printf("%c",c[i]);
    }
}
```

After I run it, I can get results and something special signs.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof(c)` will always be 100. `strlen(c)` will be the number of characters the user wrote.

Comment: But you need to include <string.h>

Comment: Yeah it really works! But the new question is that once I input something, the output will take a line feed by itself.. How come.. Thank you very much!

Comment: @forfun: Let's read the documentation for [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets): _Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character._

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof c` yields the size of an **array of char**, while `strlen(str)` tells you the length of the corresponding **C-style string**. In your case, the later one is called for.

> But the new question is that once I input something, the output will
>   take a line feed by itself

Use `c[strlen(c) - 1] = '\0'` to overwrite the '\n' with a null-terminator.